# Помогите разобраться с системой разграничения доступа в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

В Django я *новичок*, медитирую уже несколько часов над одним вопросом. Помогите разобраться.

**Цель такая:** нужно отобразить на странице ссылку только для определенной группы пользователей.

**Мой "план":** создать группу пользователей и присвоить ей право видеть ссылку. Потом в шаблоне каким-то образом проверить наличие такого права и вывести ссылку при положительном результате.

**Вопрос:** как это реализовать? (что я не понимаю на данный момент)

- Я создаю нужную группу через панель администратора. Как присвоить этой группе необходимый permission (скажем, 'can_see_link')? И в каком файле это нужно указать?
- Как в шаблоне задать условие для отображения ссылки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Django [права](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.Permission) неотъемлемы от моделей. Стандартный набор прав на добавление, изменение и удаление создаётся в базе данных вместе с таблицей модели. Можно создать [нестандартное право](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions), определив поле `permissions` в мета-классе модели:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("view_task", "Can see available tasks"),
            ("change_task_status", "Can change the status of tasks"),
            ("close_task", "Can remove a task by setting its status as closed"),
        )
```

или программно

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

from blog.models import Publication

content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Publication)
permission = Permission.objects.create(
    codename='can_publish',
    name='Can Publish Posts',
    content_type=content_type,
)
```

но привязка к модели быть должна. Выдать группе права можно в панели администратора. А [проверить их в шаблоне](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions) например так:

```
{% if perms.blog.can_publish %}
    <a href="{% url 'blog:publish' %}">Опубликовать</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Сасибо огромное, все получилось))